# Curl Euro Symbol

Tags: csv, curl, utf-8

I am curling for a csv file forma remote sever using the following curl call:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8"  ftp://user:password@ftp.url.com:21/file.csv | iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 > tmp.csv
```

When I check the tmp.csv file the Euro symbol (€) is displaying as <80>

Checking the csv file on the sever the € is displaying correctly so I think something is not encoding correctly during the curl process.

Googling has suggesting adding -H "Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8"  or iconv -f iso8859-1 -t utf-8 to my call but this is not helping.

Help me stackoverflow your my only hope.

A side question, why does the € symbol cause a lot of encoding issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source file, I believe, contains the byte `0x80`, which is a control character in ISO-8859-1 and the euro sign in Windows 1252.

When you invoke `iconv` the way you did, using ISO-8859-1 as the input encoding, it treats the byte `0x80` as codepoint U+0080, which the editors either don't display, display as a rectangle, or display as `<80>`.

You most likely want Windows 1252, which treats byte `0x80` as U+20AC, aka the euro sign:

```
curl ftp://user:password@ftp.url.com:21/file.csv | iconv -f cp1252 -t utf-8 > tmp.csv
```

BTW, your header, which I removed, specifies the type of the *request*, not the *response*. And the request is empty.